# YAML current date in rmarkdown

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

I'm wondering if there's a trick to put the current date in the YAML front-matter of a `.rmd` document to be processed by `knitr` and the `rmarkdown` package. I used to have the following line at the top of my wiki pages,

```
   _baptiste, `r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`_
```

and it would get converted to *baptiste, 03 May, 2014* in the html output. Now, I would like to take advantage of the advanced pandoc wrapper provided by `rmarkdown`, but having r code in the YAML header doesn't seem to work:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
date: `r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`
author: baptiste
---

Error in yaml::yaml.load(front_matter) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 6, column 7
 found character that cannot start any token at line 6, column 7
Calls: <Anonymous> ... output_format_from_yaml_front_matter -> 
       parse_yaml_front_matter -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
```

Any workaround?

Comment: I'm surprised that this no longer works, since this is exactly what I used to do. I'll see what was going on recently. BTW, yaml also supports values computed from R via `!expr`, e.g. `date: !expr Sys.time()`, but now this does not work either.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky, but you just need to make the `date` field valid in YAML by quoting the inline R expression, e.g.

```
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
```

Then the parsing error will be gone, and the date will be generated in the markdown output so Pandoc can use the value from `Sys.time()`.

Comment: I guess this means inline R can't be used for e.g. a list `includes: after_body: [ ... ]` as valid YAML would only be filename strings... So no possibility of ```includes: "`r list.files(...)`"``` ?

Comment: @Yihui this works for me in the html output, but not in the resulting `.md` file if I have `keep_md: true` in the YAML header. Any solution for this?

Comment: For any other Americans: `date: "\`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')\`"`.

Comment: Hi @Yihui, I got garbled month in date output in the pdf file. Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: If you need a dot in the date, keep in mind to escape them and to escape the escapes: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d\\\\. %B %Y')`

Comment: what is `r` here?

Comment: @JananathBanuka Syntax for inline R expressions: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/basics.html

Comment: This command will show the month using the default language of the system, but would it be possible to show the month on a different language? For example, if my system has English as default language, could the month be shown in, say, French?

Comment: Is it possible to get current date + 3 days?

Comment: @mikolajsemeniuk `format(Sys.Date() + 3, '%d %B, %Y')`

Answer (score 88):

Just following up on @Yihui.  Oddly, I have found that:

```
'`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
```

works better than:

```
"`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
```

For the latter RStudio chooses to change the outer quotes to `'` whenever switching between HTML and PDF output and thus breaking the code.

Comment: Was the backslash meant to be there?

Comment: The backslashes should not be there. Without them, the code works.

Comment: agreed. "" didn't work for me but '' did. thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Or just single quote the double quotes and vice versa, This works well.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
author: baptiste
---
```

Answer (score 12):

One workaround is to use the `brew` package and write your YAML front matter as a `brew` template.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
date: <%= format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y") %>
author: baptiste
---
```

You can now use a `brew_n_render` function that would preprocess the doc using `brew` and then run in through `rmarkdown`.

```
brew_n_render <- function(input, ...){
  output_file <- gsub("\\.[R|r]md$", ".html", input)
  brew::brew(input, 'temp.Rmd');  on.exit(unlink('temp.Rmd'))
  rmarkdown::render('temp.Rmd', output_file = output_file)
}
```

To make this work with the `KnitHTML` button in RStudio, you can write a custom output format that will automatically use `brew` as the preprocessor. Using `brew` to preprocess ensures that the `knitr` code chunks in your document are untouched during the preprocessing stage. Ideally, the `rmarkdown` package should expose the metadata in its API and allow users to run it through a custom function.

Comment: thanks Ramnath, that would work. It would be nice not to have the extra steps and temp files in the workflow; in my experience the more convoluted the process, the less it is reproducible (i.e. I can't remember how it works) a few months later.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, if you use the new format quarto https://quarto.org. you can do this in your yaml header of a .qmd file.

```yaml
——-
title: title of my doc
date: today
format:
  html:
    theme: default
——-
```

For formatting, check formating options [here](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/dates.html#date-formatting).

As an example,

```
date: 03/07/2005
date-format: long
```

Answer (score 4):

or, perhaps something like the following, see [R Markdown Parameterized Reports](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html#parameter_types)

```
params:
  reportDate:
    input: date
    label: 'Report Date:'
    value: as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]For the same problem  for me. I solve it using this code  .

```
---
title: "bla bla"
author: "My name"
date: \`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`\
output: html_document
---
```

**Update** 
You can use another format too .

```
---
title: "bla bla"
author: "My name"
date: \`r format(Sys.Date(), "%m %d,%Y")`\
output: html_document
---
```

Best.

Answer (score -1):

I was bitten by this today.
I had

```
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`"
```

and got more or less the same error as the OP, but **only** when knitting to word. Knitting to pdf was fine before I tried knitting to Word. Afterwards it didn't work either.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(front_matter) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 3, column 31
 found character that cannot start any token at line 3, column 31
Calls: <Anonymous> ... output_format_from_yaml_front_matter -> 
       parse_yaml_front_matter -> <Anonymous> -> .Call`
```

Position 31 is the first % sign

Replacing this with

```
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
```

as advised by MLaVoie, worked fine.

I have no idea why this happened, and I don't have time to go digging - reports to finish.