# Share configuration options not related to output

Tags: r, r-markdown

In rmarkdown you can create a file `_output.yaml` which has common options for output formats only ([reference](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#shared-options))

```
html_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: ['--base-header-level', 2]
pdf_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: ['--base-header-level', 2]
```

My question is, **is it possible to share non-output options in _output.yaml?** Closer to the format used as frontmatter in standard rmarkdown.

e.g.:

```
bibliography: ../library.bib
author: me
output:
    html_document:
        toc: true
        pandoc_args: ['--base-header-level', 2]
    pdf_document:
        toc: true
        pandoc_args: ['--base-header-level', 2]
```

such that any document I `render` in that directory will automatically get author 'me', the specified bibliography path and the output options? (Currently if I do this it complains about an `eval` call, basically trying to evaluate the value of my first option. `"object '..' not found"`).

It would be handy to avoid replicating some of the non-output-format-specific options in a single file (e.g. author, bibliography).

I know I could work around this by (ab)using `pandoc_args`, which, being format specific, works when placed into `_output.yaml`. For example, `["--bibliography", "./library.bib", "--variable", "author:me"]` would work in this case, but perhaps not in every case.

This could also be worked around if I could string multiple documents together to be concatenated into a single document; this is what `pandoc` does. For example `pandoc config.yaml chapter1.md chapter2.md` works, but `render(c('config.yaml', 'chapter1.md', 'chapter2.md'))` doesn't.

Aside: is there a way to set a default option for *all* output formats (e.g. I want to use `toc: true` for all output formats by default) without having to replicate it?

Comment: Interesting question.  This one is vaguely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23449319/602276