# Generating a PDF file with R markdown and knitr, using a R object into YAML header

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, knitr

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813420/using-r-markdown-and-knitr-possible-to-get-r-objects-interpreted-in-yaml), I want to use a R object into a YAML header using `R Markdown` and `knitr`.

The difference in my case is that the R object (`year`, a numeric) is not generated with the Rmd file, but already exists before the Rmd "knitting". Thus, I load a Rdata where this object is stored, and then write the YAML header. The top of my Rmd file looks like this:

````
```{r global_options, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
load('\\\\folder/MyData.Rdata')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=15, fig.height=8)
```

---
title : "Analysis for year `r year`"
author : "Dric"
output : pdf_document
---
````

After knitting, the document is successfully created, with a correct title, but into HTML format, not PDF. How can I create a PDF file in my case?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is related to the inline R code? Does it knit in PDF if you remove that?

Comment: It does knit in PDF when I remove the code chunk (and change the ``r year`` into an actual year).

Comment: I just tested and it worked fine here, the only drawback was that clicking on "Knit PDF" on RStudio always added a new `output : pdf_document` to get begginig of the file, because it failed to recognize the `---` section. Regardless, the PDF had the expected title.

Comment: Based on what you did, I just tried this:


`---
author : "Dric"
output : pdf_document
---

```{r global_options, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
load('\\\\folder/MyData.Rdata')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=15, fig.height=8)
```
---
title : "Analysis for year `r year`"
---`

It's weird, but it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what [Molx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724200/molx) commented, I just tried this:

````
---
author : "Dric"
output : pdf_document
---

```{r global_options, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
load('\\\\folder/MyData.Rdata')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=15, fig.height=8)
```
---
title : "Analysis for year `r year`"
---
````

It's weird, but it does exactly what I want.

Comment: I think that once `knitr` starts to knit the RMarkdown and doesn't see the `output : pdf_document` section (because you have a chunk before the heading section), it makes the output html and later it can't change that. Note that you can accept your own answer, you should do it.