# Why are some strings in quotes but others aren't when creating a .YAML file from R?

Tags: r, yaml

I'm trying to create the following `.YAML` file:

```
summary:
  title: "Table tabs"
  link: ~
  blocks: []
  nested: nav-pills
  nested_names: yes
```

(note there are no quotes around the tilde, square brackets or `yes`).

I write the code to create it in R:

```
tabs <- list(
        summary = 
            list(
                title = "Table tabs", 
                link = "~", 
                blocks = "[]", 
                nested = "nav-pills",
                nested_names = "yes"
                )
            )

write(yaml::as.yaml(tabs), file = "myfile.yaml"
```

But when I write it out to .YAML, it looks like this:

```
summary:
  title: Table tabs
  link: '~'
  blocks: '[]'
  nested: nav-pills
  nested_names: 'yes'
```

i.e. There are quotations around the tilde, square brackets and yes.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: You should show us the code you used to write it out.

Comment: I've updated this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is already provided in stackoverflow:
I try to point you through the given answers:

More general considerations using quotes in yaml are discussed sufficiently in the question "[YAML: Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20don%27t%20need%20quotes.,%25%20%2C%20%40%20%2C%20%5C%20)"

Here the difference of `'` and `"`in yaml is discussed:
"[What is the difference between a single quote and double quote in Yaml header for r Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394661/what-is-the-difference-between-a-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-yaml-header-fo)"

Specifically the tilde sign is discussed here:
"[What is the purpose of tilde character ~ in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990175/what-is-the-purpose-of-tilde-character-in-yaml)"

To summarise,

> The tilde is one of the ways the null value can be written. Most
> parsers also accept an empty value for null, and of course null, Null
> and NULL

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from TarJae, the solution is as follows:

```
tabs <- list(
        summary = 
            list(
                title = "Table tabs", 
                link = NULL, 
                blocks = list(), 
                nested = "nav-pills",
                nested_names = TRUE
                )
            )
```

Comment: Perfect icedcoffe. Thanks!