# Why is knitr changing my Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to render a pdf using Rmarkdown and knitr. This process changes the following line of my script:

```
"`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
```

to:

```
'`r format(Sys.time(), ''%B %d, %Y'')`'
```

Specifically, these double single quotes around `''%B %d, %Y''` are throwing up the message:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 5, column 31found character that cannot start any token at line 5, column 31
```

Why is knitr making these adjustments automatically, and can it be fixed / turned off?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

I have checked the answers here [YAML current date in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) but did not solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: Your fix does indeed work - it's just a different date format than we specified. The other questions correct answer did not work - and I realize now that the changing of quotes seems to happen when switching between html and pdf rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be

```
{r format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y %Z")}
```

More information can be found here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html  , if you want to change the structure of timing

*%a* is Abbreviated weekday name in the current locale on this platform.

*%b* is Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform.

*%d* is Day of the month as decimal number (01–31)

*%X* is Time. Locale-specific on output

*%Y* is Year with century.

*%Z* is Time zone abbreviation as a character string (empty if not available)