# RMarkdown Parameterise a Report

Tags: r, parameters, r-markdown

I have a report in R which generates charts and has some text. The text contains a reference to the previous week which is is itself based on a dataframe

I cant get it to run. Below is the code. Does anyone see the problem

I get the following error message

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
>     Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5, column 9
>   Calls:  ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 ->  -> .Call
>   Execution halted

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "John Smith"
date: "18 October 2016"
output: word_document
  params:
  weeknr: !r max(data$WEEKNRs)
---

```{r}

# creates the dataframe referenced in the header
source('transform.R')

```

All,

Please find below [attached](www.stackexchange.com) report for week ``r params$weeknr``
````

Comment: Is data in your global environment by chance? You need to create data in your markdown document itself. Rmarkdown is built to be a self contained script and so doesn't pull object written to the global environment by other scripts. In other words you can't use an object in your param section unless calling the Rmarkdown with a render function.

Comment: Try setting weeknr to an arbitary value and then call `render(rmarkdowndoc.rmd,params=(weeknr=max(data$WEEKNRs))`

Comment: Hi @Morgan, the variable itself is basically in the last week in the dataframe `data`. By sourcing transform.R it should create the dataframe and store it within the file? Would Rmarkdown be able to pick this up? In your second comment, thus this information get put into an R Chunk?

Comment: Yes you can pull it into your Rmarkdown with source . You could then just assign Max(data$WEEKNRs) to an object and use it in your Rmarkdown. But you can't use it in the params section.

Comment: can you show me an example of this? - referencing R code in the description section of the document

Comment: If transform.R returns data, then you could do this : `weeknr: !r max(source(transform.R)$WEEKNRs)` or it might need to be this if transform.R returns a list`weeknr: !r max(source(transform.R)[[1]]$WEEKNRs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you indented `params:` on the line after word_document.

It is possible to have code in the header, but you need to format it differently, see 
[YAML current date in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown#23529410)

In your case you can use something like (used the title tag in order to be able to easily see the result):

```
---
title:  "`r source('transform.R'); max(data$WEEKNRs)`"
---
```