# YAML current date in blogdown

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, blogdown

There's a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) that deals with the formatting of dates for R Markdown. I'm using the blogdown package, and the answers there lead me to believe I could use: `` '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")`' `` in the YAML front matter. Running `format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")` in the console gives me the date exactly as it would be in a regular Hugo blog post (i.e. "2017-02-03"), but this doesn't work with `serve_site()` (the post comes out as Jan 1 0001). Any ideas for how to get around this? Or is it necessary to use `date: "2017-02-03"`?

*edit with doc example:*

```
---
title: "new post"
author: Robert McDonnell
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")`'
categories:
  - R
  - yaml
tags:
  - R
draft: true
---
```

The error returned from `build_site()` is:

```
ERROR: 2017/02/03 13:41:23 page.go:555: Failed to parse date '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")`' in page post/x.html
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your document?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer sure, just did.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem but I am not sure where the problem lies. But since you opened a GitHub issue anyways, lets see what the developers say :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug of **blogdown** and should be [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/c575343a75cff87f9d50edecb37cb122003cf1e8) now. Please reinstall the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown).

BTW, I don't think it is a good idea to use a dynamic date for blog posts, because the URL of a post may depend on its date (e.g. if you have set the format of [permanent links](https://gohugo.io/extras/permalinks/) to something like `"/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"`). You may have a fixed date in YAML, but a dynamic one in the body of your post like

```
This post was last updated on `r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")`.
```

Comment: Thanks Yihui. It was more for when I am writing drafts, because I may start a draft and then not actually finish it for a while, but I'd like the date to be the date it was finished on.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to point out the caveat (the permanent link can change after the date is changed). If you are aware of the potential issue, please feel free to use a dynamic date temporarily before you finish the post.