# How do I insert a static value into an rmarkdown template?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'd like to generate a template for rmarkdown that automatically inserts **static**  values into the template.  Specifically, I'd like to insert the current date (formatted as DD Month YYYY) into the header and text and the current user's name into the header.

```
---
title: "Template Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "The Date"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---

# Version History

* The Date: Initial version
```

Where it currently says `Your Name` and `The Date`, I'd like those to be replaced with the current username and formatted date (as occurs when creating a new rmarkdown document in RStudio).

**Edit**:  As I'm looking for static and not dynamic values, this question differs from [YAML current date in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown).

Comment: is the username coming from RStudio server?

Comment: I like the idea, but from my understanding, the insertion of static date and title values is done within the RStudio code. You can see the stock R Markdown template [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/resources/templates/r_markdown_v2.Rmd). You could consider using extracting the current date within the YAML as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown)?

Comment: @Nate, I'm not sure how RStudio does it (that's what I'm trying to find out).  I'd be OK with the username coming from the system (Linux, Windows, or Mac) or RStudio.  But, I specifically need it to be static not a dynamic system query (so, a call to `whoami` in Linux isn't what I need).

Comment: @MichaelHarper, Do you have a verification that the static date is coming from within RStudio (if so, please post that as the answer and I'll give credit)?  That is the behavior I want to replicate.  For my template needs, the current, dynamic date as described in the other answer isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Struggling to find definitive proof, but I can't see anything within the R Markdown package which would be capable of directly doing this. I think you could get a solution working whereby you use the `writeLines` function to add this static data to your file, but this probably won't be done in the same way that RStudio does it.