# Using YAML set parameters IN YAML header Knitr with parameters

Tags: r, latex, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I declare my parameter `Report_Date` in my YAML header in R Markdown.  I want to use the `Report_Date` parameter as a forced header in header-includes the line after it.  No matter which characters I use I can't seem to reference that parameter.

I've tried any variation I could think of and followed all the other SO I've found. Even though some have almost identical questions, the answers don't work for me, or I'm doing something else wrong.

```
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{"'r params$Report_Date'"}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{r params$Report_Date}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\"'r params$Report_Date'"}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\r params$Report_Date'}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{'`r params$Report_Date`'}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{'r params$Report_Date'}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{$"'r params$Report_Date'"$}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{$"'r params$Report_Date'"}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\$r params$Report_Date'"$}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{$"'r params$Report_Date'"$}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{$'r params$Report_Date'$}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{"r params$Report_Date"}
```

even tried:

```
includes:

in_header:'`r params$Report_Date`'
```

as told in: [YAML current date in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown)

This is my current YAML R Markdown code (it is NOT in a separate template file, just in my regular .rmd file that I want to create)

```
 ---
    title: "Monthly Diagnostic Report"
    author: "Morgan :)"
    date: "July 12, 2019"
    toc: true
    params:
      Report_Date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
    header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \pagestyle{fancy}
    - \fancyhead[CO,CE]{Monthly Diagnostic Report}
    - \fancyhead[LO,LE]{"'r params$Report_Date'"}
    - \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    output: pdf_document
    ---
```

Preferably I'd have a left header that evaluates `paste0("Report Created for: ", params$Report_Date)` and a footer that evaluates `paste0("Report Created on: ",  format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y"))`.

But for now I'd settle for just a header contains the `Report_Date` parameter.

Error messages include:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r `
```

Comment: Have you tried \`r params$Report_Date\`?

Comment: yes I have, it has the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only syntax that would make sense to me is

```
---
output: pdf_document
params:
      Report_Date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{`r params$Report_Date`}
---
```

If I use that I get a different error message about `params` being unknown. This does make sense, since `params` is defined only after the YAML header has been parsed. Fortunately one can use `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` also in the body of your document (after `\begin{document}` in LaTeX speak). Hence the following should give you the desired output:

```
---
output: pdf_document
params:
      Report_Date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[CO,CE]{Monthly Diagnostic Report}
- \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
---

\fancyhead[LO,LE]{Report created for: `r params$Report_Date`}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Report created on: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`}

<actual content>
```

Note: I am setting the creation date in the body as well, since it is difficult to get a literal colon into the YAML header.

Comment: how do I format it? I add the bottom 2 lines to the last of my code (not in a chunk) and it didn't even show anything on those two extra headers, so I added it to a chunk and it didn't like that it started with a / `Quitting from lines 28-31 (Monthly_Diagnostic_Reporting_Code.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:2:1: unexpected input
1: # ALL COMMENTS ARE IN THE 6TH CHUNK, CHUNKS AFTER ARE ALL IDENTICAL 
2: \
   ^`
So I added a - to it and now I get a parse code error ...

Comment: @morg these two lines should come *before* the actual content.

Comment: yes this worked! Thanks so much!! I tried FOR DAYS and no other forum had this answer stated in such easy terms :)