# Have different .RMD file and output file names

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having troubles name my output PDF file from my "Knit with Parameters" RMD file.  my YAML header looks something like this:

```
---
title: "Discounting"
output: pdf_document 
#with more parameters for later
---
```

My file is called "Discounting Script.rmd"

Now, when I run my rmd file, the output PDF is called "Discounting Script.pdf" I'd like to make it something like "Discounting " & Sys.Date() & ".pdf" but I seem to be unable to.  I could "save as" for the rmd file if I'm able to do that somewhere in the code below to get a similar name.  I can't use rmarkedown::render because I have to knit with parameters (and I've tried the render, and I only get errors)

I want to add a part under output so it looks something like this:

```
---
title: "Discounting"
output: pdf_document
     output_file: "Discounting " & Sys.Date() & ".pdf"
---
```

I've also tried"

```
 ---
    title: "Discounting"
    output: pdf_document
         output_file: paste0("Discounting ",Sys.Date(),".pdf")
    ---
```

But neither work and they both throw errors. This should be a simple action to complete, but I can't find anything online that helps me.

Here's the 'whole file' everything under the YAML header works fine, it's just the header I have problems with.

````
---
title: " Discounting"
output: pdf_document 
  output_file: `r paste0("Discounting ", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")`
params:
  CPI: 
    label: "CPI:"
    value: .02
  Federal_Bonds: 
    input: slider
    label: "Federal Bonds are on rows:"
    min: 6
    max: 12
    value: [7,8]
    step: 1
    round: 1
    dragRange: true
  Provincial_Bonds:  
    label: "Provincial Bonds are on rows:"
    min: 10
    max: 35
    step: 1
    round: 1
    value: [15, 28]
  Corporate_Bonds:  
    label: "Corporate Bonds are on rows:"
    value: [35,86]
    min: 30
    max: 100
    round: 1
    step: 1
---

```{r eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis", message = FALSE}
Federal_Start <- params$Federal_Bonds[1]
Federal_End <-params$Federal_Bonds[2]
Provincial_Start <- params$Provincial_Bonds[1]
Provincial_End <- params$Provincial_Bonds[2]
Corporate_Start <- params$Corporate_Bonds[1]
Corporate_End  <- params$Corporate_Bonds[2]
CPI <- params$CPI
```


```{r eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis", message = FALSE}
#loading packages
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(treemapify)
library(devtools)
library(digest)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(ggrepel)
library(readxl)
library(tvm)
library(jrvFinance)
library(lubridate)
```

```{r eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis", message = FALSE}
printSectionTitle <- function (title) {
 cat("","\n\n")
 template <- title
 cat(sprintf(template),"  \n")
}
```

```{r eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis", message = FALSE} 
port_table <- c(Federal_Start, Federal_End, Provincial_Start, Provincial_End, Corporate_Start, Corporate_End, CPI)
```


```{r eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis", message = FALSE}
#Formatting the tables and creating a pretty report
printSectionTitle(sprintf("# %s","The Company"))
printSectionTitle(sprintf("# %s","Merging of Bond Portfolio with Other Risk Free Assets"))
printSectionTitle(sprintf("## %s",paste0("as at ", format(as.Date(Start_Date), "%d %B %Y"))))


colnames(port_table) <- c("","")
port_kable <- kable(port_table, align = "r",col.names = NA)
port_kable <- row_spec(port_kable, row = c(4, 7), bold = TRUE, underline = TRUE)
print(kable_styling(port_kable, bootstrap_options = "striped",latex_options = "hold_position", position ="left"))
```
````

The above code gets this error
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3, column 14
Calls:  ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> 
Execution halted

Comment: Yaml headers don't take Excel code (first example) or raw R code (second example), but you can use `\`r paste0(...)\`` (as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23449319).

Comment: While I think that this is a duplicate of that link, your comment *"can't use rmarkdown::render"* is also an issue: how are you trying to use parameters, and what is happening? Please be specific, including providing a minimal working example or at least the verbatim errors you get (with substantiating code).

Comment: title: "IBNR Discounting"
output: pdf_document 
  output_file: `r paste0("IBNR Discounting ", Sys.Date, ".pdf")`

gets the following error
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3, column 14
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Comment: Comments are horrible at maintaining layout of non-trivial code or data. If it's relevant to the question, please add it to the question. Thanks! (But if that's your literal code, do you instead mean to use `Sys.Date()`, including the parens?)

Comment: Updated, with code.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `rmarkdown::render` to render your R Markdown output (called discounting.Rmd here), from a separate .R script. You can assign your parameters in the `params` argument:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  "test_knit.Rmd",
  params = list(cpi = 10),
  output_file = paste0("Discounting_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
)
```

And your Rmd file would look something like this:

````
---
params:
  cpi:
output: pdf_document
title: "Discounting"
---

### Content

```{r}
params$cpi * 5
```
````

This will produce a PDF output named with today's date.

Comment: with the same parameter set up in the YAML header?

Comment: I need to knit with parameters though first so that I can add my own parameters in the Userform that shows up

Comment: Yeah, you can put your parameters in the render call - I added an example. This is more reproducible than using the R Studio knit functionality.